# How to show status of current Twitch streams?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, streaming

I am trying to make an index for the local streaming community.

I am working on some template code to start.

Below is a mockup - The tick representing LIVE and the X representing OFFLINE (My end product will be more appealing - this is just for visualization.)

[image]

My code template

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<p id="display"></p>

<script>
$.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/Jonathan_x64', function(channel) {

if (channel["stream"] == null) { 
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "NOT LIVE";

} else {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "LIVE";

}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, though you should try visiting the URL in your browser for which you are trying to access JSON data. You will notice that you receive a `bad request`. This is because you must also pass in a client ID with your request.

The [Twitch documentation](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5#getting-a-client-id) explains how you can go about obtaining this. Once you've obtained a client ID, you can modify your URL to add it as a parameter:

`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/Jonathan_x64?client_id=XXXXX`

Once you've done this, your code will work as expected.